# Keyframe not showing all items

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I have a simple text slider which contains 5 elements, unfortunately, the slide shows only three items.

Here is my jsfiddle: [live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ng4bpmd1/5/)

Here is my HTML so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="slider-wrapper">
          I can write
          <div class="slider">
              <div class="slider-text1">HTML</div>
              <div class="slider-text2">Java</div>
              <div class="slider-text3">PHP</div>
              <div class="slider-text4">SOCIAL.</div>
              <div class="slider-text5">LOUD.</div>
          </div>
        </div>       
      </div>
    </body>
```

Here is my CSS  for the animation.

```
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Franklin Gothic Medium", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
}
.content {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.slider-wrapper {
  font-size: 40px;
  color:#aaa;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.slider{
  height: 50px;
  padding-left:15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slider div {
  color:#fff;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding: 2px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.slider-text1 {
background: lightgreen;
animation: slide 3s linear infinite;
}
.slider-text2 {
  background: skyblue;
}
.slider-text3 {
  background: lightcoral;
}
.slider-text4 {
  background: green;
}
.slider-text5 {
  background: orange;
}
@keyframes slide {
  0% {margin-top:-300px;}
  5% {margin-top:-200px;}
  33% {margin-top:-200px;}
  38% {margin-top:-100px;}
  66% {margin-top:-100px;}
  71% {margin-top:0px;}
  100% {margin-top:0px;}
}
```

What do I need to change in my code so that all elements should appear in my slider? any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```css
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Franklin Gothic Medium", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
}
.content {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.slider-wrapper {
  font-size: 40px;
  color:#aaa;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.slider{
  height: 50px;
  padding-left:15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slider div {
  color:#fff;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding: 2px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.slider-text1 {
background: lightgreen;
animation: slide 4s linear infinite;
}
.slider-text2 {
  background: skyblue;
}
.slider-text3 {
  background: lightcoral;
}
.slider-text4 {
  background: green;
}
.slider-text5 {
  background: orange;
}
@keyframes slide {
  0% {margin-top:-500px;}
  8% {margin-top:-500px;}
  16% {margin-top:-400px;}
  24% {margin-top:-400px;}
  32% {margin-top:-300px;}
  40% {margin-top:-300px;}
  48% {margin-top:-200px;}
  56% {margin-top:-200px;}
  64% {margin-top:-100px;}
  72% {margin-top:-100px;}
  80% {margin-top:0px;}
  88% {margin-top:0px;}
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="slider-wrapper">
          I can write
          <div class="slider">
              <div class="slider-text1">HTML</div>
              <div class="slider-text2">CdfddfSS</div>
              <div class="slider-text3">PHP</div>
              <div class="slider-text4">SOCIAL.</div>
              <div class="slider-text5">LOUD.</div>
          </div>
        </div>       
      </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your css code ,

```
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Franklin Gothic Medium", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
}
.content {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.slider-wrapper {
  font-size: 40px;
  color:#aaa;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.slider{
  height: 50px;
  padding-left:15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slider div {
  color:#fff;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding: 2px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.slider-text1 {
background: lightgreen;
animation: slide 3s linear infinite;
}
.slider-text2 {
  background: skyblue;
}
.slider-text4 {
  background: lightcoral;
}
.slider-text3 {
  background: green;
}
.slider-text5 {
  background: orange;
}
@keyframes slide {
  0% {margin-top:-500px;}
  20% {margin-top:-400px;}
  40% {margin-top:-300px;}
  60% {margin-top:-200px;}
  80% {margin-top:-100px;}
  100% {margin-top:0px;}
}
```

Comment: let me check I will come back

Comment: NOT working. text is sliding without posing,  the slider should work as my demo but instead of 3 elements, I want 5 elements

Comment: did you check out?